# How do we prove the following?

Tags: inequality, computational-mathematics, binary-operations

The expression is:

a<sub>1</sub> | a<sub>2</sub> |⋯| a<sub>n</sub> **≤** a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> +⋯+ a<sub>n</sub>
, where '|' denotes the [Bitwise OR operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, each bit of the `OR` of two numbers is independent from each other. That is,

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^N a_i2^i\right) \mid \left(\sum_{i=0}^N b_i2^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^N (a_i \mid b_i) 2^i$$

So it suffices to show this for $a_i, b_i \in \{0, 1\}$. However, that is easy, since

1. For $a_i = b_i = 0$, $a_i \mid b_i = 0 \leq 0 + 0 = 0$.
2. For $a_i = 0, b_i = 1$ or the other way around, $a_i \mid b_i = 1 \leq 0 + 1 = 1$.
3. For $a_i = b_i = 1$, $a_i \mid b_i = 1 \leq 1 + 1 = 2$.

---

With a similar proof, you have $a + b = (a \mid b) + (a \& b)$ where $\&$ is the bitwise AND operation.

From this, use induction.

Comment: Instead of the trial and error method, you showed, is there any step-by-step generic proof for this?

Comment: @SuryaTejaChavali its not trivial and error, this is the definition of the operators